# Getting 'not supported jsx syntax' error during the jest tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Used SVG as a ReactComponent and during the jest test getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: corner-resize-arrow.svg: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (1:1):
<svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 14 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
    <path d=-"M12 8.58307e-05L3.05176e-05 12L3.1209e-05 9L9
      8.51393e-05L12 8.58307e-05Z" fill="white"/>
    <path d="M6 5.34058e-05L-4.76837e-06 5.99988L-4.5538e-06 2.99988L3
      5.31912e-05L6 5.34058e-05z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/IfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your
Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-isx
(https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing,
```

But I already have @babel/preset-react in my config file.

```
module.exports = {
    "presets": ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
    "plugins": ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
}
```

Here is the jest config inside pckage.json file.

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom":[
        "**/src/**"
        "!**/node_modules/**",
        "!**/src/index**",
        "!**/src/const**"
        "!**/src/Redux/constants**"
        "!**/coverage/**"
        "!**/public/**"
        "!**/tests/**"
        "!**/webpack/**",
        "!**/babel.config.js**"
        "!**/src/serviceWorker.js**"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
        "lcov"
        "text"
        "clover"
        "json"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory":"./coverage",
    "setupFiles": [
        "./src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
         "'\(ess|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "testResultsProcessor":"jest-sonar-reporter"
}
```

Note: NPM start command works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `presets` in the babel config is missing the `@` for the `preset-env` entry:

```
module.exports = {
    "presets": ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
    "plugins": ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
}
```

Comment: It is my bad, really sorry, it was a typo. It is not working with @ also

Comment: No worries. Can I check `@babel/preset-env` is definitely in your `package.json` and youve installed the package? Can I also ask, if you are using `babel-jest` and its configured in your project? If the second question is alien to you, I think I know what it is.

Comment: Actually, posting your Jest configuration as well by editing your original question would be helpful :)

Comment: @babel/preset-env version 7.7.1 is in package.json file. Also I have only @babel/preset-react and babel-polyfill. No babel-jest

Comment: Cool, give me a sec to add another answer.

Comment: Installed babel-jest, still didn't work, added jest config to the original question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246954/discussion-between-red-fox-and-adam-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `babel-jest` installed in your project, you will need to add it. `npm install --save-dev babel-jest` could do the trick if you use NPM as your package manager.

It is automatically detected and used by Jest.